# Extract records from a list only if they have a matching element name

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr

If I have a list with completely unpredictable and seemingly nonsensical nesting like so:

```
weird_nested_structure <- (list(
  Record = "First Record",
    Pets = list(Rabbit = "True", 
                Gerbil = "True"),
  Record = "Second Record",
    Pets = list(Pets2 = list(Rabbit = "True")),
  Record = "Third Record",
    Rabbit = list(Rabbit = "True"),
  Record = "Fourth Record",
    Pets = list(Dog = "True")))
```

How can I extract only the records that have an element named "Rabbit"?

This would return records 1, 2 and 3, but **not** 4 because the only elements in record 4 are named "Pets" and "Dog"

To be clear, I want to filter this list down to only the records that contain a name/variable called "Rabbit", regardless of which level of nesting this variable happens to be in. So the ideal solution will return a list of records 1, 2 and 3 but not 4 from the above nested list.

Is this possible in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in base R would be to write a recursive function which checks for names at every level if `any` name in the list contains the name `"Rabbit"`

```
recursive_fun <- function(x) {
  if (any(names(x) == "Rabbit"))
      return(TRUE)
  if (is.list(x))
      recursive_fun(unlist(x, recursive = FALSE))
  else 
      return(FALSE)
}
```

and then use `sapply` to pass it to each list and subset the ones which return `TRUE`

```
weird_nested_structure[sapply(weird_nested_structure, recursive_fun)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - on the above structure this method achieves the output: "Record   Pets Record   Pets Record Rabbit Record   Pets 
 FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE" - is there a way to return the same list, but reduced to only the records that have a list element (or nested list element) named "Rabbit"?

Comment: @DavideLorino yes, you need to subset it. I edited it later, check updated answer.  Do `weird_nested_structure[sapply(weird_nested_structure, recursive_fun)]`

Comment: Amazing thank you! One last question (extra credit ;) ) is there a way to return the entire list, with TRUE indicating that there is an element name == "Rabbit", and FALSE indicating that there is no element name == "Rabbit"?

Comment: @DavideLorino that's what the initial `sapply` call gave right? If you need it as a list you can use `lapply`, `lapply(weird_nested_structure, recursive_fun)`